# Kubernetes on Docker Desktop - local connectivity issue using a service between two pods

Tags: kubernetes, service, yaml, kubernetes-pod, connectivity

I have created an ASP.NET Core C# Kubernetes Microservice *(Named: 'DemoApi')* with an Angular Frontend app *(Named: 'DemoApp')*.

Despite the fact that it works when I run both containers through `Docker for Desktop` or `Docker Swarm Mode`, I seem to have some connectivity issues when I run through `Kubernetes on Docker Desktop`.

To clarify the issue, I can display both

- the front-end application at `http://localhost:30005`
- the back-end application at `http://localhost/demo`

but while running the pods using Kubernetes, the front-end application **does not display the data it should get** from the API back-end.

Despite my search, I could not find a similar problem to mine. What could be the problem? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**The following is a short summary of the steps I took:**

1. Defined the applications to read one from the other.

   a. DemoApi:

   ```cs
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {

          services.AddControllers();
          services.AddCors(options =>
          {
              options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularDevClient",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
              options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularClient",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
          });
      }
   ```

   b. DemoApp (under `app.component.ts`):

   ```angular
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'DemoApp';
      response = "No data loaded, yet";
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
      { 
        this.http.get('http://localhost/demo', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((response: any) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.response = response;     
        });
      }
   ```
2. Built the applications into an image

   a. Built the ASP.NET Core C# using the default Visual Studio docker support (Using the solution explorer, Right-click the dockerfile > `Build Docker Image`).

   b. Created a `dockerfile` for the angular application as follow:

   ```dockerfile
    FROM node:14-alpine as build-step
    RUN mkdir -p /app
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY package.json /app

    RUN npm install
    COPY . /app
    RUN npm run build --prod

    FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine
    COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/DemoApp /usr/share/nginx/html
   ```

   then ran the command `docker build -t demoapp .`

✔️ Worked using Local Docker for Desktop

- `docker run --name demoapi-container demoapi`
- `docker run --name demoapp-container --publish 4200:80 demoapp`

✔️ Worked using Local Docker Swarm Mode

- `docker service create --name demoapi-svc -p 80:80 demoapi`
- `docker service create --name demoapp-svc -p 4200:80 demoapp`

❌ Did not work using Local Kubernetes for Docker Desktop

- DemoApi:

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    name: demo-api-pod
    labels:
      name: demo-api-pod
      app: demo-api
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: demo-api-container
        image: demoapi:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: demoapi
    labels:
      name: demo-api-svc
      app: demo-api
  spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port:  80
      targetPort:  80
    selector:
      name: demo-api-pod
      app: demo-api
  ```
- DemoApp:

  ```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: demo-angular-pod
      labels:
        name: demo-angular-pod
        app: demo-angular
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demo-angular-container
          image: demoapp:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: demoapp
      labels:
        name: demo-angular-svc
        app: demo-angular
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - port:  80
        targetPort:  80
        nodePort: 30005
      selector:
        name: demo-angular-pod
        app: demo-angular
  ```

---

**EDIT:** I have completely re-configured everything starting from scratch thanks to @darwinawardee's suggestion:

At my DemoApi app I've added to the controller:

```cs
options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularKubernetesClient",
builder =>
{
    builder
    .WithOrigins("http://demoapp").WithOrigins("demoapp").WithOrigins("http://localhost:30005")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod();
});

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAngularKubernetesClient");
    [...]
}
```

At my DemoApp app I've added to `app.component.ts`:

```angular
constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
{ 
    this.http.get('http://demoapi/demo', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response + " -- from Kubernetes Cluster.");
        this.response = response;       
    });
}
```

and re-built the images.

I've done the same process, yet the DemoApp does not get the information from the DemoApi.

Here are the logs from the entire process:
[image: Kubernetes pods process and logs]

This is the result of using native Chrome's Inspect > Network tab:
[image: Chrome Network Debug]

Comment: To better understand the problem, you are trying to expose a backend and a frontend at the same ip address and at the same port with Kubernetes for Docker Desktop? Or at two different IPs available from the outside?

Comment: @AndD Looking at the Kubernetes part, the frontend application (DemoApp) should be visible at `http://localhost:30005`, while the backend application (DemoApi) should be visible at `http://localhost/demo`. They both are, but the frontend application does not show the data from the backend application, as it cannot reach its api data.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Have you checked any logs? Do you have any http error codes? You say it doesn't work, but what exactly is happening? Do you have any errors, information, warnings? What version of kubernetes are you using? Why do you use `type: LoadBalancer` in `demoApi` and  `type: NodePort` in the `DemoApp`? What exactly did you set up in the cluster?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I have added more details to the issue I described above, including the logs. Thank you for your attention. Regarding your questions: (1) The problem is that *DemoApp* does not get the info from *DemoApi*. (2) I tried to expose the different pods in different ways on my end. My end goal is for *DemoApi* to be `ClusterIP` (not-exposed) and *DemoApp* to be as `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` (exposed).

Comment: Which Kubernetes version did you use? I will try to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will be facing a network routing issue.

In Kubernetes each deployment will run in a pod which is assigned it's own IP address, as is the associated service for each (which load balances traffic across pods). Kubernetes maintains an [internal DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) for routing between services. A service can be reached by it's full route servicename.namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example or within the namespace simply via the servicename itself.

So for the traffic to reach the DemoApi you'll the DemoApp to query http://DemoApi/demo rather than http://localhost/demo.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Although I enabled CORS inside the API application and read from `http://demoapi/demo`, it still doesn't work. I have added some information regarding your suggestion to the original post. I would appreciate your assistance with this issue.

Comment: I suspect your service types are wrong if you refer to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types), you'll want a ClusterIP on the API (internal traffic only) and a LoadBalancer on the App.